# Is $a-a=0$ defined or can it be proved by using any axioms?

Tags: real-analysis

Following is a partial proof for the trichotomy of integers from Terence Tao's book *Real Analysis*:

Lemma 4.1.5 (Trichotomy of integers).

Let $x$ be an integer. Then
exactly one of the following three statements is true:

(a) $x$ is zero;

(b) $x$ is equal to a positive natural number n; or

(c) $x$ is the negation -n of a positive natural number n.

Proof. We first show that at least one of (a), (b), (c) is true. By
definition, $x$ = $a-b$ for some natural numbers $a, b$. We have three
cases: $a > b, a = b, or a < b$.

If $a > b$ then $a = b + c$ for some
positive natural number $c$, which means that $a-b = c-0 = c$,
which is (b).

If $a= b$, then $a-b =a-a= 0-0 = 0$ which is (a).

If $a < b$, then $b > a$, so that $b-a = n$ for some natural number $n$ by the previous reasoning, and thus $a-b = -n$, which
is (c).

Can anyone explain the below statement

> If $a= b$, then $a-b =a-a= 0-0 = 0$
> which is (a).

How is $a-a=0-0$?I understand this might be a trivial question but i am also new to real analysis.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: what do the axioms say about $0$? How is $-$ defined?

Comment: If $a=b$, then $a-b= a-a= 0$.  That $a-a  = 0 = 0-0 = 0+ 0$ does not mean $a=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering this question calls for a careful look at Tao's text, in particular Definition 4.1.1:

> An *integer* is an expression of the form $a-b$, where $a$ and $b$ are
> natural numbers. Two integers are considered to be equal, $a-b = c-d$,
> if and only if $a + d = c + b$.

(There is a footnote attached to "expression" elaborating on the notion of equivalence relation on ordered pairs of natural numbers.) That's how one gets from $a-a$ to $0-0$.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the question in the title:

> Is $a-a=0$ defined or can it be proved by using any axioms?

It boils down to the definition of $x-y$.

One common definition is $x-y=x+(-y)$, where by definition $-y$ is such that $y+(-y)=0$.

In this sense, $a-a=0$ is by definition.